# Why am I not starting in My Career NBA2k14 PS4

Tags: nba2k14

So a few games ago I got promoted to a sixth-man. Now it's been like 11 games, I play 27 minutes on the bench, but still don't start. I get a great performance rating every time, put up 30 points a game, 5th best pg in the NBA. I play for the Philadelphia 76'ers, and I got a better overall than the guy who is starting over me. So my question is why am I not starting yet? I've played like 45 games with them now...

Comment: I'm even the top scorer by far in the team.

Comment: Now yesterday started playing 28 minutes, played 15 games with 28 minutes, still not starting. AND now I'm the top scorer in the NBA.

Comment: 70 games in the season, still same team, still not started. The couch keeps saying I will add more minutes, keep up the good work, but doesnt talk about starting me, he said keep up the good work like 10 times, when i get 28, minutes on the bench. And 28 is max, and he can't add more minutes, so why isn't he starting me?

Comment: I think this is a glitch, I ran into this issue too in but was in 2k13. I was put in as a starter at some point, but after an injury I came off the bench every game, even though I get put in within seconds of the game starting and would play every minute after that. No matter what I did I wasn't chosen as a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, most people who post on the forums say that they start starting somewhere between halfway and a full season. By your second year, you should be in the starting 5. 2K sports has said that they plan to release a patch that allows your player to start earlier. No word yet on when this patch will be released.

Comment: Will I just start then, or will I need to work hard like I do now?

Comment: As long as you are consistent with your numbers (points, rebounds, assists etc) you will start sometime between the halfway point and the end of the season. This information is according to most of the forum posts and other people's experiences with the game. The exact algorithm used is unknown, so it's hard to pinpoint exactly.

Comment: Is avg 40 points a game, 2 assists, 2 rebounds a game good enough to start?

Comment: I would work on your other stats. Try to be more well-rounded. 20-25 points a game, 10 rebounds, 10 assists. Getting triple doubles is a way more impressive than 40 points a game.